# HISTORY_STALE_THRESHOLD option doesn't work

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, xlm

After referring to [this documentation](https://developers.stellar.org/docs/run-api-server/ingestion#managing-stale-historical-data), I set HISTORY_STALE_THRESHOLD to 0 to prevent 503 Historical DB is too stale error when I submit a transaction.

[This stellar-core code](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/flags.go#L487) says 0 is the default value in the option, meaning infinite(=never return to any stale error)

```
// in horizon.env
export HISTORY_STALE_THRESHOLD=0
```

However, the same error occurs.

Does anyone know how to avoid this error?